# some css will not load in production mode in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt.js 2.9.1 for new project and I use some third party library like vue-select. in development mode everything works fine but in production mode the css will not load !!! i use npm run generate for generating project

```
css: [
    '@neneos/nuxt-animate.css',
    '@assets/fontawesome-pro-5.8.2-web/css/all.css',
    'animate.css/animate.css',
    'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css'
],
plugins: [
    {
      src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/vee-validate'`enter code here`
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/vue-select',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/vue-tooltip',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/axios'
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/vue-tags-input',
      ssr: false
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/vue-masonry',
      ssr: false
    }
]
```

Comment: Hey! did you fix this problem?

Comment: My vue-select CSS is not loading on production. I guess you also had the same problem. How did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
      src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist',
      mode: 'client',
      ssr: false
    },
```

or

```
{
      src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist',
      mode: 'server',
      ssr: false
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is fixed by providing css file in head section of nuxt.config.js :

```
   link: [{
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/x-icon',
        href: '/favicon.ico'
      },
      {
        rel: 'preload',
        as: 'style',
        onload: "this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'",
        href: '/vue-select.css',
      }

    ]
```

however it will be considered as a render blocking resource by google page inspection and this is SEO issue. so i will add these 3 properties:

```
    rel: 'preload',
    as: 'style',
    onload: "this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'",
```